# "Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one" message in R

Tags: r

Say, I have the following data:

```
LungCap Age Height  Smoke   Gender  Caesarean
6.475   6   62.1    no      male    no
10.125  18  74.7    yes     female  no
9.55    16  69.7    no      female  yes
11.125  14  71      no      male    no
4.8      5  56.9    no      male    no
6.225   11  58.7    no      female  no
```

Now kindly look at the following command:

```
> attach(LungCap6)
> tapply(Age, Smoke, mean, T)
Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
> length(Age)
[1] 6
> tapply(X=Age, INDEX=Smoke, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)
  no  yes 
10.4 18.0 
> tapply(Age, Smoke, mean, T)
Error in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
>
```

Why is the above error being given, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please use `TRUE` or the parameter name as there would be other parameters also in `tapply`

Comment: @akrun, problem is not resolved by that.

Comment: Could be, I am suggesting some good practice so that in the future it wouldn't be an issue (also using `with` instead of `attach`)

Comment: @akrun, oh! I have been just learning R for the last 2 days.

Comment: The second argument of `mean` is `trim`,  `na.rm` is the third. When you do `... mean, TRUE)` you pass `TRUE` to `trim` but not when you name your argument like in the second case.

Comment: @markus, okay. so, what should I write then?

Comment: I guess you should go with `tapply(X = Age, INDEX = Smoke, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)`, no? But as akrun pointed out, try not to use `attach`.

Comment: @markus, no. I mean, if I want to write it without argument-names?

Comment: Why would you want that? You would need to pass the default to `trim`, i.e. `tapply(X = Age, INDEX = Smoke, mean, 0, TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trim=` is the second argument of the function `mean()`, and you don't want to pass `TRUE` to that argument when called within `tapply()`. That's what `tapply()` does, it passes extra args preserving the order to the function it calls.

Thus, you have to explicitly name the argument you want to send `TRUE`, in this case `na.rm=`, since it is the 3rd and not the 2nd argument to `mean()`:

```r
> attach(LungCap6)
> tapply(Age, Smoke, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Check the argument order with `?mean`