# Mutate a new variable across multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe, mutate, across

I have this following data.frame. Each value in CP variables are in the same format -> hueX:Y-Z.

hueX is always the same in a row.

I would like to create another variable with value equal to

- the value of CP_A if TCK_A!="Yes",
- otherwise I would like the output to be equal to "hueX:mean(Y)-mean(Z)" across CP_B, CP_C and CP_D

```
data_trial = data.frame(hue=c(2,8,3,2,5),
          CP_A=c("hue2:6789-99987", "hue8:7854-98743","hue3:60987-123423","hue2:7658-873457","hue5:45658-676549"),
          CP_B=c("hue2:6782-99987", "hue8:7859-98734","hue3:60989-123407","","hue5:45697-676598"),
          CP_C=c("hue2:6785-99989", "hue8:6797-99980","hue3:60995-123434","hue2:7657-8734509","hue5:45667-676500"),
          CP_D=c("", "hue8:6756-99987","hue3:60942-123412","hue2:7650-87345065","hue5:45699-676565"),
          TCK_A=c("Yes", "", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"))

> data_trial
  hue              CP_A              CP_B              CP_C               CP_D TCK_A
1   2   hue2:6789-99987   hue2:6782-99987   hue2:6785-99989                      Yes
2   8   hue8:7854-98743   hue8:7859-98734   hue8:6797-99980    hue8:6756-99987      
3   3 hue3:60987-123423 hue3:60989-123407 hue3:60995-123434  hue3:60942-123412   Yes
4   2  hue2:7658-873457                   hue2:7657-8734509 hue2:7650-87345065   Yes
5   5 hue5:45658-676549 hue5:45697-676598 hue5:45667-676500  hue5:45699-676565   Yes


output

  hue              CP_A              CP_B              CP_C               CP_D TCK_A             output
1   2   hue2:6789-99987   hue2:6782-99987   hue2:6785-99989                      Yes    hue2:6784-99988
2   8   hue8:7854-98743   hue8:7859-98734   hue8:6797-99980    hue8:6756-99987          hue8:7854-98743
3   3 hue3:60987-123423 hue3:60989-123407 hue3:60995-123434  hue3:60942-123412   Yes  hue3:60975-123418
4   2  hue2:7658-873457                   hue2:7657-8734509 hue2:7650-87345065   Yes hue2:7654-48039787
5   5 hue5:45658-676549 hue5:45697-676598 hue5:45667-676500  hue5:45699-676565   Yes  hue5:45688-676554
```

What I have tried :

```
  data_trial %>% 
  separate(CP_B, into=c("hueX_B","Y_BxZ_B"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_C, into=c("hueX_C","Y_CxZ_C"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_D, into=c("hueX_D","Y_DxZ_D"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(Y_BxZ_B, into=c("Y_B", "Z_B"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_CxZ_C, into=c("Y_C", "Z_C"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_DxZ_D, into=c("Y_D", "Z_D"), sep="-") %>%
  mutate(Y_B=as.numeric(Y_B)) %>%
  mutate(Y_C=as.numeric(Y_C)) %>%
  mutate(Y_D=as.numeric(Y_D)) %>%
  mutate(Z_B=as.numeric(Z_B)) %>%
  mutate(Z_C=as.numeric(Z_C)) %>%
  mutate(Z_D=as.numeric(Z_D)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(CP_output=ifelse(TCK_A=="Yes", paste0("hue", hue, ":", mean(across(c(Y_B, Y_C, Y_D)), na.rm=TRUE), "-", mean(across(c(Z_B,Z_C,Z_D)), na.rm=TRUE)), CP_A))

# A tibble: 5 × 13
# Rowwise: 
    hue CP_A              hueX_B   Y_B    Z_B hueX_C   Y_C     Z_C hueX_D   Y_D      Z_D TCK_A CP_output      
  <dbl> <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>          
1     2 hue2:6789-99987   "hue2"  6782  99987 hue2    6785   99989 ""        NA       NA "Yes" hue2:NA-NA     
2     8 hue8:7854-98743   "hue8"  7859  98734 hue8    6797   99980 "hue8"  6756    99987 ""    hue8:7854-98743
3     3 hue3:60987-123423 "hue3" 60989 123407 hue3   60995  123434 "hue3" 60942   123412 "Yes" hue3:NA-NA     
4     2 hue2:7658-873457  ""        NA     NA hue2    7657 8734509 "hue2"  7650 87345065 "Yes" hue2:NA-NA     
5     5 hue5:45658-676549 "hue5" 45697 676598 hue5   45667  676500 "hue5" 45699   676565 "Yes" hue5:NA-NA
```

The first steps are working but might be simplified.
The last step is not working. I have correct result only in the FALSE condition.

I still have difficulties to work accross multiple columns and repeat some identical operations on multiples columns. Any ideas to help me.

EDIT

I have also tried this following code and I get correct means but uncorrect hue value (the contrary compared to my first attempt)

```
data_trials_2 = data_trial %>% 
  separate(CP_B, into=c("hueX_B","Y_BxZ_B"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_C, into=c("hueX_C","Y_CxZ_C"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_D, into=c("hueX_D","Y_DxZ_D"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(Y_BxZ_B, into=c("Y_B", "Z_B"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_CxZ_C, into=c("Y_C", "Z_C"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_DxZ_D, into=c("Y_D", "Z_D"), sep="-") %>%
  mutate(Y_B=as.numeric(Y_B)) %>%
  mutate(Y_C=as.numeric(Y_C)) %>%
  mutate(Y_D=as.numeric(Y_D)) %>%
  mutate(Z_B=as.numeric(Z_B)) %>%
  mutate(Z_C=as.numeric(Z_C)) %>%
  mutate(Z_D=as.numeric(Z_D))

  data_trials_2$CP_output= paste0("hue", rowwise(data_trials_2[,1]), ":", round(rowMeans(data_trials_2[,c(4,7,10)], na.rm=TRUE)) , "-",    round(rowMeans(data_trials_2[,c(5,8,11)], na.rm=TRUE)))

data_trials_2$CP_output
[1] "huec(2, 8, 3, 2, 5):6783.5-99988"                     
[2] "huec(2, 8, 3, 2, 5):7137.33333333333-99567"           
[3] "huec(2, 8, 3, 2, 5):60975.3333333333-123417.666666667"
[4] "huec(2, 8, 3, 2, 5):7653.5-48039787"                  
[5] "huec(2, 8, 3, 2, 5):45687.6666666667-676554.333333333"
```

Comment: Hi Av65 - In your first bullet point you say `output == CP_A ` if `TCK_A=="Yes"`, but in the work you've shared you are applying the opposite (`output` is the average of the other values when `TCK_A=="Yes"`.

Comment: Thank you, the error is in the first bullet, i will edit my question.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but every answer (and even your question, and the attempts at an answer in your question) have different values, so it'd be good to have one definitive thing we're all trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`separate` from `tidyr` has been superseded, so I will use `separate_wider_delim`.

Once columns are separated, you end up with convenient column names to use `tidy-select` functions like `contains`, allowing you to `mutate` `across` in place of multiple `mutate` calls.

This example doesn't keep the original column data, but you can by setting `cols_remove = FALSE` in `separate_wider_delim`.

***Edit*** Updated to replace `rowwise` operations with `rowMeans`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

```r
data_trial %>%
  separate_wider_delim(starts_with('CP'), delim = ':', names = c('hue', 'values'),
                       names_sep = '_', too_few = 'align_end') %>%
  separate_wider_delim(ends_with('_values'), delim = '-', names = c('Y', 'Z'),
                       names_sep = '_', too_few = 'align_end') %>%
  mutate(across(contains('values'), as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(mean_Y = rowMeans(across(matches("[^A]_values_Y")), na.rm = T),
         mean_Z = rowMeans(across(matches("[^A]_values_Z")), na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(output = if_else(TCK_A != 'Yes',
                          paste0('hue',hue,':',CP_A_values_Y,'-',CP_A_values_Z),
                          paste0('hue',hue,':', mean_Y, '-', mean_Z))) %>%
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 5
#> Columns: 17
#> $ hue           <dbl> 2, 8, 3, 2, 5
#> $ CP_A_hue      <chr> "hue2", "hue8", "hue3", "hue2", "hue5"
#> $ CP_A_values_Y <dbl> 6789, 7854, 60987, 7658, 45658
#> $ CP_A_values_Z <dbl> 99987, 98743, 123423, 873457, 676549
#> $ CP_B_hue      <chr> "hue2", "hue8", "hue3", NA, "hue5"
#> $ CP_B_values_Y <dbl> 6782, 7859, 60989, NA, 45697
#> $ CP_B_values_Z <dbl> 99987, 98734, 123407, NA, 676598
#> $ CP_C_hue      <chr> "hue2", "hue8", "hue3", "hue2", "hue5"
#> $ CP_C_values_Y <dbl> 6785, 6797, 60995, 7657, 45667
#> $ CP_C_values_Z <dbl> 99989, 99980, 123434, 8734509, 676500
#> $ CP_D_hue      <chr> NA, "hue8", "hue3", "hue2", "hue5"
#> $ CP_D_values_Y <dbl> NA, 6756, 60942, 7650, 45699
#> $ CP_D_values_Z <dbl> NA, 99987, 123412, 87345065, 676565
#> $ TCK_A         <chr> "Yes", "", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
#> $ mean_Y        <dbl> 6783.500, 7137.333, 60975.333, 7653.500, 45687.667
#> $ mean_Z        <dbl> 99988.0, 99567.0, 123417.7, 48039787.0, 676554.3
#> $ output        <chr> "hue2:6783.5-99988", "hue8:7854-98743", "hue3:60975.3333…
```

#### Data

```r
data_trial <- data.frame(hue=c(2,8,3,2,5),
                        CP_A=c("hue2:6789-99987", "hue8:7854-98743","hue3:60987-123423","hue2:7658-873457","hue5:45658-676549"),
                        CP_B=c("hue2:6782-99987", "hue8:7859-98734","hue3:60989-123407","","hue5:45697-676598"),
                        CP_C=c("hue2:6785-99989", "hue8:6797-99980","hue3:60995-123434","hue2:7657-8734509","hue5:45667-676500"),
                        CP_D=c("", "hue8:6756-99987","hue3:60942-123412","hue2:7650-87345065","hue5:45699-676565"),
                        TCK_A=c("Yes", "", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working as I want but when applying to my real data, I face a problem at the mean step when I have two NA and only one non NA value. I get this error message "'trim' must be numeric of length one". I tried to understand why and i notice that mean(565, NA, na.rm=TRUE) lead to the same error message, while mean(565, na.rm=TRUE) and mean(565, 765,  NA, na.rm=TRUE) are fine. How can I solve this problem ? I can open a new question for this specific problem if needed.

Comment: Seth you could replace `rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    mean_Y = mean(CP_B_values_Y, CP_C_values_Y, CP_D_values_Y, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean_Z = mean(CP_B_values_Z, CP_C_values_Z, CP_D_values_Z, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()` with `mutate(
    mean_Y = rowMeans(across(matches("[^A]_values_Y")), na.rm = T),
    mean_Z = rowMeans(across(matches("[^A]_values_Z")), na.rm = T))`

Comment: @Av65 one way of fixing the problem you're having is by swapping out the parts I mentioned in the comment above. Another way is to put the column names inside a vector, e.g. `mean_Y = mean(c(CP_B_values_Y, CP_C_values_Y, CP_D_values_Y), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816150/error-in-mean-defaultxi-trim-must-be-numeric-of-length-one-mess

Comment: Thank you again and sorry again for all the inconsistencies between myself, and the other responses. I got lost and I got mixed trying to reproduced my data. Using the response of Seth and the comment of @Mark I think I got all that I needed.

Comment: Thank you, @Mark. And glad you were able to adapt this to work with your real data, Av65.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**. Comment on the code you have. I keep 3 decimal places, assuming you don't want them endlessly long, but you can change as you wish.

```
data_trial %>% 
  separate(CP_B, into=c("hueX_B","Y_BxZ_B"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_C, into=c("hueX_C","Y_CxZ_C"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(CP_D, into=c("hueX_D","Y_DxZ_D"), sep=":") %>%
  separate(Y_BxZ_B, into=c("Y_B", "Z_B"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_CxZ_C, into=c("Y_C", "Z_C"), sep="-") %>%
  separate(Y_DxZ_D, into=c("Y_D", "Z_D"), sep="-") %>%
  mutate(Y_B=as.numeric(Y_B)) %>%
  mutate(Y_C=as.numeric(Y_C)) %>%
  mutate(Y_D=as.numeric(Y_D)) %>%
  mutate(Z_B=as.numeric(Z_B)) %>%
  mutate(Z_C=as.numeric(Z_C)) %>%
  mutate(Z_D=as.numeric(Z_D)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(CP_output=ifelse(TCK_A=="Yes", paste0("hue", hue, ":", mean(c(Y_B, Y_C, Y_D),na.rm=TRUE)%>%round(3), "-", mean(c(Z_B,Z_C,Z_D), na.rm=TRUE))%>%round(3) , CP_A%>%as.character()))
#it gives
# A tibble: 5 x 13
# Rowwise: 
    hue CP_A              hueX_B   Y_B    Z_B hueX_C   Y_C     Z_C hueX_D   Y_D      Z_D TCK_A CP_output                
  <dbl> <fct>             <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <fct> <chr>                    
1     2 hue2:6789-99987   "hue2"  6782  99987 hue2    6785   99989 ""        NA       NA "Yes" hue2:6783.5-99988        
2     8 hue8:7854-98743   "hue8"  7859  98734 hue8    6797   99980 "hue8"  6756    99987 ""    hue8:7854-98743          
3     3 hue3:60987-123423 "hue3" 60989 123407 hue3   60995  123434 "hue3" 60942   123412 "Yes" hue3:60975.333-123417.667
4     2 hue2:7658-873457  ""        NA     NA hue2    7657 8734509 "hue2"  7650 87345065 "Yes" hue2:7653.5-48039787     
5     5 hue5:45658-676549 "hue5" 45697 676598 hue5   45667  676500 "hue5" 45699   676565 "Yes" hue5:45687.667-676554.333
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve? The key issue you got is the incorrect use of `across()`, and potentially `CP_A` being character. Just use `mean()` function to get the mean from multiple column is fine.

Comment: are you sure you have the right answer? You appear to have the same value in every row that isn't row 2

Comment: @Mark Overlooked and now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, relatively concise way, which uses [`pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pmap.html), a short function and [glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/):

```
f <- \(x, y) str_extract(x, y) |> as.numeric() |> mean(na.rm = T) |> round()
data_trial |> mutate(output = ifelse(TCK_A != "Yes", CP_A, pmap(across(CP_B:CP_D), ~ glue::glue("{str_extract(c(...), '.*:')[1]}{f(c(...), '(?<=:)(\\\\d+)(?=-)')}-{f(c(...), '(?<=-)(\\\\d+)')}"))))
```

Output:

```
  hue              CP_A              CP_B              CP_C               CP_D
1   2   hue2:6789-99987   hue2:6782-99987   hue2:6785-99989                   
2   8   hue8:7854-98743   hue8:7859-98734   hue8:6797-99980    hue8:6756-99987
3   3 hue3:60987-123423 hue3:60989-123407 hue3:60995-123434  hue3:60942-123412
4   2  hue2:7658-873457                   hue2:7657-8734509 hue2:7650-87345065
5   5 hue5:45658-676549 hue5:45697-676598 hue5:45667-676500  hue5:45699-676565
  TCK_A            output
1   Yes   hue2:6784-99988
2         hue8:7854-98743
3   Yes hue3:60975-123418
4   Yes   NA7654-48039787
5   Yes hue5:45688-676554
```

Answer (score 0):

> otherwise I would like the output to be equal to "hueX:mean(Y)-mean(Z)" across CP_B, CP_C and CP_D

Here a first version of an apporach in base R. It seems like I have correctly anticipated that you want row-wise means.

```r
fst = round(colMeans(
  apply(data_trial[, c("CP_B", "CP_C", "CP_D")], 1L,
        \(x) as.numeric(gsub(".*hue[0-9]\\:(.+)\\-.*", "\\1", x))), 
  na.rm = TRUE), 0L)
snd = round(colMeans(
  apply(data_trial[, c("CP_B", "CP_C", "CP_D")], 1L,
        \(x) as.numeric(gsub(".*\\-", "\\1", x))), 
  na.rm = TRUE), 0L)

data_trial$another_var = 
  ifelse(data_trial$TCK_A != "Yes", 
         data_trial$CP_A,
         paste0(gsub("\\:.*", "\\1", data_trial$CP_A), ":", fst, "-", snd))

data_trial
#>   hue              CP_A              CP_B              CP_C               CP_D
#> 1   2   hue2:6789-99987   hue2:6782-99987   hue2:6785-99989                   
#> 2   8   hue8:7854-98743   hue8:7859-98734   hue8:6797-99980    hue8:6756-99987
#> 3   3 hue3:60987-123423 hue3:60989-123407 hue3:60995-123434  hue3:60942-123412
#> 4   2  hue2:7658-873457                   hue2:7657-8734509 hue2:7650-87345065
#> 5   5 hue5:45658-676549 hue5:45697-676598 hue5:45667-676500  hue5:45699-676565
#>   TCK_A        another_var
#> 1   Yes    hue2:6784-99988
#> 2          hue8:7854-98743
#> 3   Yes  hue3:60975-123418
#> 4   Yes hue2:7654-48039787
#> 5   Yes  hue5:45688-676554
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Data**

```r
data_trial = data.frame(hue=c(2,8,3,2,5),
                        CP_A=c("hue2:6789-99987", "hue8:7854-98743","hue3:60987-123423","hue2:7658-873457","hue5:45658-676549"),
                        CP_B=c("hue2:6782-99987", "hue8:7859-98734","hue3:60989-123407","","hue5:45697-676598"),
                        CP_C=c("hue2:6785-99989", "hue8:6797-99980","hue3:60995-123434","hue2:7657-8734509","hue5:45667-676500"),
                        CP_D=c("", "hue8:6756-99987","hue3:60942-123412","hue2:7650-87345065","hue5:45699-676565"),
                        TCK_A=c("Yes", "", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my multiple updates.. I should be able to adapt your suggestion, so no need to update your message.

Comment: See the minor update, change yes with no in `ifelse()`.